# Most Pythonic way to use a variable from one script in a second object

Tags: python

What's a good way to use a variable from one script inside the object in another file? I thought using global would work but it does not.

My config loading class has an expensive disk operation that loads the config file from disk into a dictionary. So naturally I want to avoid repeating this operation every time I need the config variables; I want to keep it in memory for all the other objects to use.

This works, but is kludgy. Aside from battery.py I have other classes not shown and need to pass config as a parameter for all.

main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from config import CONFIG
from battery import BATTERY
config = CONFIG().config
battery = BATTERY(config)
print("Running this the first time.")
battery.print_config()
print("Running again. Should not go slow.")
battery.print_config()
```

config.py:

```
class CONFIG(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Simulating the expensive disk operation
        from time import sleep
        for i in range(1, 4):
            print i
            sleep(1)

        self.config = {'parameter': 'value'}
```

battery.py

```
class BATTERY(object):
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config

    def print_config(self):
        print(self.config['parameter'])
```

Result:

```
$ ./main.py
1
2
3
Running this the first time.
value
Running again. Should not go slow.
value
```

I thought I might try to global config inside battery.py's init but that fails with the error below.

```
class BATTERY(object):
    def __init__(self): # Removed the config argument
        # Added global config
        global config
        self.config = config

    def print_config(self):
        print(self.config['parameter'])
```

Result:

```
$ ./main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 5, in <module>
    battery = BATTERY()
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/nbktvlh/Desktop/Test/battery.py", line 4, in __init__
    self.config = config
NameError: global name 'config' is not defined
```

This works but makes it more tightly coupled. (Right?) And strangely, it executes the print twice.

```
class BATTERY(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Added this line
        from main import config
        self.config = config

    def print_config(self):
        print(self.config['parameter'])
```

Result:

```
$ ./main.py
1
2
3
1
2
3
Running this the first time.
value
Running again. Should not go slow.
value
Running this the first time.
value
Running again. Should not go slow.
value
```

Maybe there's a better way to do this?

Comment: remove the config class, and simply `from config import config`?

Comment: Also, there are no true global variables in Python. "global" scope actually means "module-level" scope.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga please explain removing the config class. Won't that still cause the config file to be read every time it's imported?

Comment: I just tested it, that does work. I'll post an answer.

Comment: No. Try it yourself: `echo "print('hiya')" > verbose.py`. Now `echo "import verbose" | tee > a.py > b.py` and finally, see what happens when you import all your other modules in a main module: `echo "import a; import b" > main.py`, so `python main.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @juanpa.arrivillaga for the answer. I shouldn't make config a class.

main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from config import config
from battery import BATTERY
battery = BATTERY()
print("Running this the first time.")
battery.print_config()
print("Running again. Should not go slow.")
battery.print_config()
```

config.py:

```
# Simulating the expensive disk operation
from time import sleep
for i in range(1, 4):
    print i
    sleep(1)

config = {'parameter': 'value'}
```

battery.py:

```
class BATTERY(object):
    def __init__(self):
        from config import config
        self.config = config

    def print_config(self):
        print(self.config['parameter'])
```

Results:

```
$ ./main.py
1
2
3
Running this the first time.
value
Running again. Should not go slow.
value
```